# How do I tell `make` to `patch` an existing file avoiding circular dependency error?

Tags: makefile, patch

eg:

```
# patched foo.c depends on original foo.c and couple of my edits in foo.dif
foo.c: foo.c foo.dif
  patch foo.c foo.dif
```

I'd like to avoid filename and directory mess and just apply an edits in-place and be ready for rebuild facilitated by original makefile (which is quite complex and sensitive to filenames and directories) provided with original source tree.

---

@AUZKamath, my edits contained in that `foo.dif`. This is for deployment of my patch over existing source tree on end user system. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Why do you want patching to be dependent on foo.c ? Ideally you would patch only if there is a new diff available.

Comment: @AUZKamath, I not quite understood what did you mean. Edited a little. About that `foo.dif`: it is always available as part of distribution of my "unofficial" patch to be applied over existing source tree which end user got elsewhere.

Comment: Workflow: I fixed bug in `foo.c`, generated a `diff`, rebuilt and tested, now I want to distribute my edits w/o waiting for my patch merged into "official" source tree. And here comes a confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a so-called “sentinel” file to indicate that the patch has already been applied.

`foo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hi!\n");
}
```

`foo.diff`:

```
--- foo.c
+++ foo.c
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
-    printf("hi!\n");
+    printf("goodbye.\n");
 }
```

`Makefile`:

```
foo: foo.c

foo.c: foo.c.patched

foo.c.patched: foo.diff
    if [ -e $@ ]; then patch -R foo.c $@; fi
    patch foo.c $<
    cp foo.diff $@
```

`foo` depends on `foo.c`, and `foo.c` depends on `foo.c.patched`, which depends on the patch file. So before `foo` is built, `foo.c.patched` will be built if it does not exist or if `foo.diff` is newer. The rule for `foo.c.patched` applies the patch and then saves a copy of it.

So:

- If you have not applied the patch already, it will automatically be applied
- If you modify `foo.c`, it will be rebuilt
- If you modify the patch, the build system will revert the previously-applied patch if necessary, and then apply the new patch

You can edit either `foo.c` or `foo.diff` and, as long as you don't create conflicts during your editing, the build system will handle the rest.